# Minecraft Spawner GUI

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Well, I got the mod Spawner GUI and it's pretty cool, but I noticed it will only let you change the spawner in creative mode and NOT survival, Is there any way I can configure this? Please let me know!

Comment: Why is this tagged steam and not minecraft?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness +1 for that comment followed by your name.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to configure it in survival mode. There are no mods that will allow you to configure it in survival mode either. You will have to make a survival world and activate cheats. Then you can create your world make your spawner and then switch back to survival mode.

Comment: OK, thanks, I just wanted to know because I saw Syndicate from  TheSyndicateProject do it on survival, and when I tried it, it said "You must be an opped player on creative mode".

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative. MCedit. There is no need to install mods and it is an open source program. http://www.mcedit.net/ It is a world editor, so you can edit things with out enabling cheats.